# How to set the default value on select dropdowns with javascript after AJAX call

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a program that generates a table rows based on part selections from a dropdown menu. On each row that is created, I have a `<td>` element that contains a dropdown for quantity. My problem is that when a new part is selected thus creating a new row, all my quantity dropdowns reset back to the default value of 1. I tried fixing it with "selected = true;" but that doesn't seem to work. Basically, I need to set the selected value of each quantity dropdown to stay as whatever selected value it was last set at when the user adds a new row. I'm using an ajax call to generate the data from a SQL table on each new row.

Here is the function which is called from the select dropdown. I've omitted a lot of unnecessary code:

```
function update(){
    var selectLists = document.getElementsByName("qty_dropdown");
    for(var i = 0; i < selectLists.length; i++){
        var firstSelectList = selectLists[i].value;    
    }
}
```

Here is my dropdown:

```
<td>
    <select name = "qty_dropdown" onChange = "update()"> 
        <option value = '1'> 1 </option>  
        <option id = '2'value = '2'> 2 </option> 
        <option value = '3'> 3</option> 
        <option value = '4'> 4 </option> 
        <option value = '5'> 5 </option> 
        <option value = '6'> 6 </option> 
        <option value = '7'> 7 </option> 
        <option value = '8'> 8 </option> 
        <option value = '9'> 9 </option> 
        <option value ='10'> 10</option> 
    </td>
</select>
```

Comment: post some code and show us what you are trying. Dynamic ids will solve your problem.

Comment: added some code. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function you are performing inside `update()` (i renamed it to add() ) should be performed on the addition of new row.

```
function add(){
    var selectLists = document.getElementsByName("qty_dropdown");
    var firstSelectList=[];
    for(var i = 0; i < selectLists.length; i++){
      firstSelectList.push(selectLists[i].value);
    }
    document.getElementById("inject").innerHTML+="<select name = 'qty_dropdown' onChange = 'update()'>           <option value = '1'> 1 </option>            <option id = '2'value = '2'> 2 </option>           <option value = '3'> 3</option>           <option value = '4'> 4 </option>           <option value = '5'> 5 </option>           <option value = '6'> 6 </option>           <option value = '7'> 7 </option>           <option value = '8'> 8 </option>           <option value = '9'> 9 </option>           <option value ='10'> 10</option>           </select>     ";
    for(var i = 0; i < selectLists.length-1;i++){
    selectLists[i].value=firstSelectList[i];
    }
}
```

this function add() will add a new row without resetting previous dropdown.

Demo : https://jsfiddle.net/0wur28ot/

What i did is save the value in array before adding new row and then i assigned values to the dropdown accordingly after row addition.

Comment: if possible. I'd like to achieve the same thing but with an onchange event instead because the user doesn't click a button to add a new row but a new row is created after a category is selected and then a part.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/0wur28ot/1/ this solves your problem, onchange of select option new row is added and previous values are preserved

Comment: I haven't applied it to my code yet, as it will take some tinkering on my part. But yes, it looks like it should work. Thank you.

Comment: Glad could help you. :). If you face any problem do let me know :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way you can do it. You can keep a variable around that keeps track of the most recently selected dropdown value, and when you add a new dropdown to the DOM, it will use that value as its initial value.

```js
var lastUpdatedDropdownValue = "";

function update(event) {
  lastUpdatedDropdownValue = event.target.value;
}

function addNewDropdown() {
  var dropdown = document.querySelector("[name=qty_dropdown]");
  var newDropdown = dropdown.cloneNode(true); // make sure no duplicate IDs. If your elements that are being cloned have IDs, remove them before re-inserting into the DOM
  document.getElementById("dropdownContainer").append(newDropdown);
  var selectedOption = newDropdown.querySelector("[value='" + lastUpdatedDropdownValue + "']");
  selectedOption.selected = true;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="addNewDropdown()">Add New Dropdown</button>
<div id="dropdownContainer">
  <select name="qty_dropdown" onChange="update(event)">
    <option value='1'>1</option>
    <option value='2'>2</option>
    <option value='3'>3</option>
    <option value='4'>4</option>
    <option value='5'>5</option>
    <option value='6'>6</option>
    <option value='7'>7</option>
    <option value='8'>8</option>
    <option value='9'>9</option>
    <option value='10'>10</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. This is a good solution. However, my program generates the new table rows based on a selection from a different dropdown which contains part names. Each row shows information about the part which is pulled from the id of the selected part from the db: price, parts, hours of labor etc. So I would need to wire the addNewDropdown function to the onchange event which generates the new table rows.

Comment: @totallytypicalcow No offense, but SO isn't a code writing service for you to be able to copy and paste our code into your program and have stuff magically work. It sounds like you know exactly what you need to modify in order to take the concepts I have provided to solve your issues, therefore my work here is done. If you found my answer useful, feel free to upvote, if you found it the **most** useful answer, feel free to mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: I understand. And I apologize as I'm new to the stack overflow community and programming in general. My question on the comment was more asking you if the function will work the same way with an onchange event as it would as an onclick event. Thank you for your help and your time.

Comment: @totallytypicalcow Ah, yes, understandable. Yes, it will work exactly the same for an `onchange` event as it would from an `onclick`, it's just a function and can be called from anywhere. Yay, functions! =)